# Keyboard is not opening in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms 5 app, I have a few forms and even though everything works fine on Android, on iOS the soft keyboard doesn't open all the way. It looks like it's stuck. I see the top of a drawer -- see image below:

[image]

I don't see anything special about the layout in these forms. In most cases, I have simple `Entry` controls within `StackLayout`. Other times, I use a `Grid`.

Just to give you one example, here's a typical layout I use for a short and simple form:

```
<StackLayout>
   <Label
      Text="First Name" />
   <Entry
      Text={Binding FirstName}
      Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
   <Label
      Text="Last Name"
      Margin="0,10,0,0" />
   <Entry
      Text={Binding LastName}
      Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
   <Button
      Text="Submit"
      Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
      Margin="0,20,0,0" />
</StackLayout>
```

Any idea why the keyboard may not be opening automatically when I tap on one of the `Entry` controls?

Comment: Testing on simulator? I've seen that before. I think I fixed by simulator menu (top row of Mac) toggling (hard? soft?) keyboard on and off. Hmm, though now that I think about it, there were situations that never worked right. Fortunately, only a problem on simulator. So I use mac's hardware keyboard.

Comment: You're right that this is happening on the simulator and the toggle option in the simulator menu "helps". The keyboard works fine on a real device. Of course, there's still the keyboard covering form elements issue but that's another matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This phenomenon is reproducible in my side.
You could use [KeyboardOverlap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap/) nuget package in your iOS project and get it worked in `AppDelegate.cs` like below.

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Comment: This is not working on Shell. I'm never 
a fan of third party solutions that have not been updated for years but wanted to give it a try anyway. As the issue reported on the plugin's GitHub repo states, it doesn't work on Xamarin.Forms with Shell. https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/issues/174